# MySQL Insert & Select in same statement returns 'records' when none exist

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So I have the following code (heavily simplified) -

```
MySqlCommand CMD = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO helpdesk.calls Set CallID = @CallID, Viewed = 1, Date = current_timestamp();
SELECT * FROM helpdesk.calls WHERE ID = @CallID", Con);
CMD.Parameters.Add("CallID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ID;
using (MySqlDataReader Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader()) {
    if (Reader.Read()) {
        RetVal = ToCallHeader(Reader);
    } else {
        // this never throws as Reader.Read() always returns true.
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Call ({0}) not found", ID));
    }
}
```

where I am inserting a record and also running a select at the same time. The problem is that Reader.Read() returns true whether any rows are selected from the select statement or not when an insert statement is used. Is this behavor by design and do I require two queries with a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

That Insert Query syntax is wrong and it will throw an exception.

```
INSERT INTO helpdesk.calls Set CallID = @CallID, Viewed = 1, Date = current_timestamp();
```

Check here for the correct sql syntax on insert statement: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Thanks, the above code is simplified, the query I have is running fine, I am just trying to understand why reader.read returns true when there are no results.

Comment: What is the actual query you are sending? 
If you send two queries (like above), you will get 2 result sets back.